# How do I set a sequence of questions based on the answers selected using jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a question-answer bank. First a question is selected from a dropdown then the answers appear. Now, sub-dropdowns appear next to each answers to select the next question. So, a sequence will be generated as and when the question or answer is selected. Ex. Q1-A1-Q3-A4, Q1-A3-Q2-A1.  This should go on until all the questions are used per sequence.

I have tried my best to populate the questions and answers based on the selections. However, I am not able to set the conditions to reach to the end of the sequence. The conditions required are the following: no question should be repeated within a sequence, whereas it can be repeated in multiple sequences.

Screenshot for desired results:
[image]

**Please note: There is a character limits to the code snippets , so Please visit the codepen for entire code.**

Here is the codepen for the same:

https://codepen.io/Jagruti-S/pen/OJGJbJx

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('#default-sequence').length) {
    setDefaultSequence();
    $(document).on("change input", "input[name=sequence_order]", setDefaultSequence);
  }
  if ($("#question-type").length) {
    const singleSelect = $("#answer-type-single").clone();
    const multiSelect = $("#answer-type-multiple").clone();
    const trueFalseSelect = $("#answer-type-truefalse").clone();
    if (!$("#question-type").val()) {
      $(".answer-type-section").remove();
    }
    $(document).on("change", "#question-type", function() {
      $(".answer-div").each(function(index) {
        $(this).find('input').val("").trigger("change");
        if (index >= 4) {
          $(this).remove();
        }
      });
      $(".answer-type-section").remove();
      switch ($(this).val()) {
        case 'true-or-false':
          $("#answer-type").append(trueFalseSelect)
          break;
        case 'single-select':
          $("#answer-type").append(singleSelect);
          break;
        default:
          $("#answer-type").append(multiSelect);
      }
      $(".answer-type-section").removeClass("d-none");
    });
  }
  if ($(".questions-list").length) {
    var questionCounter = 0;
    $(".questions-list input").each(function() {
      $(this).change(function() {
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
          $(this).closest(".custom-checkbox").removeClass("bg-dark").addClass("selected bg-black");
          $(this).parent().addClass("text-white");
          questionCounter++;
        } else {
          $(this).closest(".custom-checkbox").removeClass("selected bg-black").addClass('bg-dark');
          $(this).parent().removeClass("text-white");
          questionCounter--;
        }
        if (questionCounter > 10) {
          $("#questionLimit").modal("show");
          $(this).prop('checked', false);
          $(this).closest(".custom-checkbox").removeClass("selected bg-black").addClass('bg-dark');
          $(this).parent().removeClass("text-white");
          questionCounter--;
        }
      });
    });
  }
  if ($("#sequence-creator").length) {
    var nextLevelQyestionBank = [];
    var sequenceTreeLevel = $(".sequence-tree").length;
    var finalSequences = [];
    const questionBank = $(".question-text").map(function(index) {
      const answers = $(this).parent().find(".question-answer").html().split(",").map(function(answer) {
        return answer.trim();
      });
      return {
        id: "q" + (index + 1),
        question: $(this).text(),
        answers: answers,
        disabled: false,
        type: $(this).parent().find(".question-type").data('type')
      };
    }).get();
    var selectedQuestions = [];
    var dataSeq = 1;

    function updateQuestionDropdown() {
      if (selectedQuestions.length >= questionBank.length) {
        $("#add-sequence-btn").removeAttr("disabled").removeClass("disabled");
      } else {
        $("#add-sequence-btn").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("disabled");
        $(".question-parent").removeAttr("style");
        $("#select-ques").empty().append("<option value=''></option>");
        questionBank.map(function(question) {
          if (selectedQuestions.includes(question.id)) {
            $("#select-ques").append("<option disabled value='" + question.id + "'>" + question.question + "</option>");
          } else {
            $("#select-ques").append("<option value='" + question.id + "'>" + question.question + "</option>");
          }
        });
      }
    }
    function updateAnswerDropdown(questionId) {
      $(".answer-parent").removeAttr("style");
      var question = questionBank.find(q => q.id === questionId);
      if (question && question.answers) {
        var answersDropdown = $("#select-answer");
        answersDropdown.empty();
        answersDropdown.append("<option value=''></option><option value='any'>Any</option>");
        for (var i = 0; i < question.answers.length; i++) {
          answersDropdown.append("<option value='a" + (i + 1) + "'>" + question.answers[i] + "</option>");
        }
      }
    }
    updateQuestionDropdown();
    var currentSelectQue;
    $(document).on("change", ".selection-row select", function() {
      if ($(this).val()) {
        var mainQuestion = $(this);
        var qId = $(this).val();
        var qText = $(this).find('option:selected').text;
        var question = questionBank.find(q => q.id === qId);

        //If selected question is single select or true/false then show answers else show next question selection
        if (question.type == 'true-false' || question.type == 'single-select') {
          $("<div class='sequence-tree new-tree bg-black p-3 border border-black' data-sequence-level='" + sequenceTreeLevel + "'></div>").insertBefore($(".selection-row"));
          $(".new-tree").append("<div class='selected-question'><span class='sequence-numbers'>" + qId + "</span><p>" + qText + "</p></div>");
          if (question && question.answers) {
            for (var i = 0; i < question.answers.length; i++) {
              nextLevelQyestionBank[i] = [];
              var ansDiv = "<div class='selected-answer no-question-selected'>" +
                "<span class='sequence-numbers'>a" + (i + 1) + "</span>" +
                "<p>" + question.answers[i] + "</p>" +
                "<div class='d-flex align-items-center gap-3 next-question-selection'>" +
                "<div class='select-parent'><select data-questionLevel='" + sequenceTreeLevel + "' data-answerLevel=" + i + " class='form-select level-questions' data-placeholder='Select question for level-" + sequenceTreeLevel + "' id='question-level" + sequenceTreeLevel + "-" + i + "'><option value=''></option>";
              questionBank.map(function(question) {
                if (selectedQuestions.includes(question.id)) {
                  ansDiv += "<option disabled value='" + question.id + "'>" + question.question + "</option>";
                } else {
                  nextLevelQyestionBank[i].push(question.id);
                  ansDiv += "<option value='" + question.id + "'>" + question.question + "</option>";
                }
              });
              ansDiv += "</select></div>" +
                "<span>or</span>" +
                "<div class='form-check form-checkbox'>" +
                "<label class='form-label form-check-label' for='is-subdomain'" + (i + 1) + ">default order" +
                "<input type='checkbox' id='is-subdomain'" + (i + 1) + ">" +
                "<span></span>" +
                "</label>" +
                "</div>" +
                "</div>" +
                "</div>";
              $(".new-tree").append(ansDiv);
              selectedQuestions[i] = [];
              selectedQuestions[i].push(qId);
            }
          }
        } else {
          $("<div class='sequence-tree new-tree bg-black p-3 border border-black multi-select' data-sequence-level='" + sequenceTreeLevel + "'></div>").insertBefore($(".selection-row"));
          $(".new-tree").append("<div class='selected-question'><span class='sequence-numbers'>" + qId + "</span><p>" + qText + "</p></div>");
          var ansDiv = '<div class="d-flex align-items-center gap-3 next-question-selection">' +
            '<div class="select-parent"><select data-questionLevel="' + i + '" class="form-select level-questions" data-placeholder="Select question for level-' + sequenceTreeLevel + '" id="question-' + i + '-level' + sequenceTreeLevel + '"><option value=""></option>';
          questionBank.map(function(question) {
            if (selectedQuestions.includes(question.id)) {
              ansDiv += "<option disabled value='" + question.id + "'>" + question.question + "</option>";
            } else {
              nextLevelQyestionBank.push(question.id);
              ansDiv += "<option value='" + question.id + "'>" + question.question + "</option>";
            }
          });
          ansDiv += "</select></div>" +
            '<span>or</span>' +
            '<div class="form-check form-checkbox">' +
            '<label class="form-label form-check-label" for="is-subdomain">' +
            'default order' +
            '<input type="checkbox" id="is-subdomain-2">' +
            '<span></span>' +
            '</label>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';
          $(".new-tree").append(ansDiv)
        }
        sequenceTreeLevel++;
        $(".sequence-tree").removeClass("new-tree");
      }
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (mainQuestion) {
          mainQuestion.val('').trigger('change');
          mainQuestion.unbind('change');
        }
      }, 1000);
    });
    $(document).on("change", ".level-questions", function() {
      var levelQuestion = $(this);
      var qId = $(this).val();
      var qText = $(this).find('option:selected').text;
      var ansDiv = '';
      var question = questionBank.find(q => q.id === qId);
      if (qId) {
        levelQuestion.closest('.selected-answer').removeClass("no-question-selected")
      } else {
        levelQuestion.closest('.selected-answer').addClass("no-question-selected")
      }
      if ($(this).closest('.multi-select').length && $(this).closest('.multi-select').attr('data-sequence-level') > 0) {
        var nextLEvel = "<div class='sequence-tree new-tree bg-black p-3 border border-black' data-sequence-level='" + sequenceTreeLevel + "'></div>"
        $(nextLEvel).insertAfter($(this).closest(".multi-select"));
      } else {
        var nextLEvel = "<div class='sequence-tree new-tree bg-black p-3 border border-black' data-sequence-level='" + sequenceTreeLevel + "'></div>"
        $(nextLEvel).insertAfter($(this).closest(".next-question-selection"));
      }
      $(".new-tree").append("<div class='selected-question'><span class='sequence-numbers'>" + qId + "</span><p>" + qText + "</p></div>");


      selectedQuestions[levelQuestion.attr("data-answerlevel")] = [];
      if (question.type == 'true-false' || question.type == 'single-select') {
        if (question && question.answers) {
          for (var i = 0; i < question.answers.length; i++) {
            nextLevelQyestionBank[i] = [];
            ansDiv = "<div class='selected-answer no-question-selected'>" +
              "<span class='sequence-numbers'>a" + (i + 1) + "</span>" +
              "<p>" + question.answers[i] + "</p>" +
              "<div class='d-flex align-items-center gap-3 next-question-selection'>" +
              "<div class='select-parent'><select data-questionLevel='" + i + "' class='form-select level-questions' data-placeholder='Select question for level-" + sequenceTreeLevel + "' id='question-" + i + "-level" + sequenceTreeLevel + "'><option value=''></option>";
            questionBank.map(function(question) {
              if (selectedQuestions.includes(question.id)) {
                ansDiv += "<option disabled value='" + question.id + "'>" + question.question + "</option>";
              } else {
                nextLevelQyestionBank[i].push(question.id);
                ansDiv += "<option value='" + question.id + "'>" + question.question + "</option>";
              }
            });
            ansDiv += "</select></div>" +
              "<span>or</span>" +
              "<div class='form-check form-checkbox'>" +
              "<label class='form-label form-check-label' for='is-subdomain'" + (i + 1) + ">default order" +
              "<input type='checkbox' id='is-subdomain'" + (i + 1) + ">" +
              "<span></span>" +
              "</label>" +
              "</div>" +
              "</div>" +
              "</div>";
            $(".new-tree").append(ansDiv);

            selectedQuestions[levelQuestion.attr("data-answerlevel")][i] = [];
            selectedQuestions[levelQuestion.attr("data-answerlevel")][i].push(qId);
          }
        }
      } else {
        $("<div class='sequence-tree new-tree bg-black p-3 border border-black multi-select' data-sequence-level='" + sequenceTreeLevel + "'></div>").insertBefore($(".selection-row"));
        $(".new-tree").append("<div class='selected-question'><span class='sequence-numbers'>" + qId + "</span><p>" + qText + "</p></div>");
        ansDiv = '<div class="d-flex align-items-center gap-3 next-question-selection">' +
          '<div class="select-parent"><select data-questionLevel="' + i + '" class="form-select level-questions" data-placeholder="Select question for level-' + sequenceTreeLevel + '" id="question-' + i + '-level' + sequenceTreeLevel + '"><option value=""></option>';
        questionBank.map(function(question) {
          if (selectedQuestions.includes(question.id)) {
            ansDiv += "<option disabled value='" + question.id + "'>" + question.question + "</option>";
          } else {
            nextLevelQyestionBank.push(question.id);
            ansDiv += "<option value='" + question.id + "'>" + question.question + "</option>";
          }
        });
        ansDiv += "</select></div>" +
          '<span>or</span>' +
          '<div class="form-check form-checkbox">' +
          '<label class="form-label form-check-label" for="is-subdomain">' +
          'default order' +
          '<input type="checkbox" id="is-subdomain-2">' +
          '<span></span>' +
          '</label>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>';
        $(".new-tree").append(ansDiv)
      }
      sequenceTreeLevel++;
      $(".sequence-tree").removeClass('new-tree');
      $("html").css('--sequenceBottom', ($("#sequence-outer > .sequence-tree").height() - $("#sequence-outer > .sequence-tree > .selected-answer:last-child").height() - 35) + "px");
    });
  }
});

function setDefaultSequence() {
  $('#default-sequence').text('');
  $("input[name=sequence_order]").each(function(index) {
    if (index > 0) {
      var text = "-q";
    } else {
      var text = "q";
    }
    $('#default-sequence').text($('#default-sequence').text() + text + $(this).val());
  });
}
```

```css
:root {
  --bs-dark: #0c0c0c;
  --bs-dark-rgb: 12, 12, 12;
  --bs-dark-rgb: 15, 15, 15;
  --bs-primary: #f83881;
  --bs-primary-hover: #F40962;
  --bs-primary-rgb: 248, 56, 129;
  --bs-secondary: #6e87ee;
  --bs-secondary-hover: #4f62b0;
  --bs-secondary-rgb: 110, 135, 238;
  --bs-success: #1fdda1;
  --bs-success-rgb: 31, 221, 161;
  --bs-info: #7089f0;
  --bs-info-rgb: 112, 137, 240;
  --bs-body-color: #ccc;
  --bs-link-color: #ccc;
  --bs-link-color-rgb: 204,204,204;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
body:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: var(--bs-dark);
  opacity: 0.97;
}
#main-content {
  gap: 30px;
}
#main {
  overflow: hidden;
}
span.sequence-numbers {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background: var(--bs-dark);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 60px;
  border: 1px solid;
  color: #fff;
}
.selected-question span.sequence-numbers {
  border-color: var(--bs-primary);
}
.selected-answer span.sequence-numbers {
  border-color: var(--bs-secondary);
}
.selected-question {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 15px;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
}
.selected-question p {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #666;
  margin: 0;
}
.selected-answer {
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
  margin: 0 0 25px 60px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
}
.selected-answer p {
  margin: 0;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #666;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.sequence-tree {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.sequence-tree:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  bottom: 175px;
  bottom: 90px;
  bottom: 0;
  bottom: calc(1em + 30px);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 50%, var(--bs-dark) 50%), linear-gradient(to bottom, #00b9ff, #59d941);
  background-size: 100% 20px, 100% 7px;
  left: 45px;
}
#sequence-outer > .sequence-tree:before {
  height: var(--sequenceBottom);
}
.selected-answer:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, #223049 50%), linear-gradient(to right, #00b9ff, #59d941);
  background-size: 16px 2px, 100% 2px;
  width: 30px;
  transform: translateY(30px);
}
.selected-answer .sequence-tree {
  flex: 100%;
  margin-left: 45px;
  overflow: visible;
}
.selected-answer > p {
  margin-top: 18px;
}
.selected-answer .selected-question span.sequence-numbers {
  border-color: var(--bs-primary);
  position: relative;
}
.selected-answer .selected-question span.sequence-numbers:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, #223049 50%), linear-gradient(to right, #00b9ff, #59d941);
  background-size: 16px 2px, 100% 2px;
  width: 30px;
  transform: translateY(30px);
  top: 0;
}
.selected-answer:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 50%, var(--bs-dark) 50%), linear-gradient(to bottom, #00b9ff, #59d941);
  background-size: 100% 20px, 100% 7px;
  left: 30px;
  height: 65px;
}
.sequence-tree.multi-select, .selected-answer .sequence-tree.multi-select {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 15px;
}
.sequence-tree.multi-select .next-question-selection, .selected-answer .sequence-tree.multi-select .next-question-selection {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}
.sequence-tree .form-check.form-checkbox label.form-check-label {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.selected-question:last-child {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}
.selected-question.last-question {
  margin: 0;
}
.selected-answer .sequence-tree.multi-select + .sequence-tree {
  margin-left: 120px;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.selected-answer .sequence-tree.multi-select .selected-question {
  margin: 0;
}
.selected-answer .sequence-tree.multi-select + .sequence-tree::before {
  left: 25px;
  top: 60px;
}
.selected-answer .sequence-tree.multi-select + .sequence-tree::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -27px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 50%, var(--bs-dark) 50%), linear-gradient(to bottom, #00b9ff, #59d941);
  background-size: 100% 20px, 100% 7px;
  left: -30px;
  height: 60px;
}
.selected-answer.no-question-selected:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.selected-answer.no-question-selected:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}
.sequence-tree > .sequence-tree {
  margin-left: 45px;
  transform: translateY(-30px);
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<body class="d-flex bg-dark w-100" style="overflow: hidden;">
  <section class="d-flex flex-fill flex-nowrap" id="main" style="position: relative;">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-fill" id="right-content" style="overflow: hidden;">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-fill p-3" id="main-content" style="overflow: hidden;">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-fill gap-4" style="overflow: hidden;">
          <div class="d-flex flex-fill overflow-auto">
            <form class="d-flex flex-column flex-fill gap-3" id="sequence-creator" action="questions-based-on-roles.html">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row gap-3">
                  <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column mb-3 gap-2"><label class="form-label mb-0">role based questions</label>
                      <div class="ms-auto"><span class="fw-semibold">default sequence:&nbsp;<span id="default-sequence" class="text-secondary">q1-q2-q3-q4-q5</span></span>
                      </div><small class="align-items-center ms-auto">enter the order number against the question to set the default sequence of the questions</small>
                      <div class="d-flex flex-column gap-5" id="sequence-outer">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                          <table class="table table-hover table-dark table-borderless dtTable">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th class="no-sort text-nowrap">SR. no.</th>
                                <th class="no-sort">question</th>
                                <th class="no-sort text-nowrap">question type</th>
                                <th class="no-sort">answers</th>
                                <th class="no-sort order-col">order</th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td class="question-text">Are you currently working?</td>
                                <td class="question-type" data-type="true-false">True or false</td>
                                <td class="question-answer">Yes, No</td>
                                <td class="order-col"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="sequence_order" value="1" placeholder="0"></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>What are your top 5 skills?</td>
                                <td class="question-type" data-type="multi-select">Multi select</td>
                                <td class="question-answer">Problem solving, requirements gathering, team coordination, project management, project delivery, pressure handling, task allotment, All of the above</td>
                                <td class="order-col"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="sequence_order" value="2" placeholder="0"></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td class="question-text">What is the largest team size you have handled so far?</td>
                                <td class="question-type" data-type="single-select">Single select</td>
                                <td class="question-answer">0-10, 10-30, 30-50, 50+</td>
                                <td class="order-col"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="sequence_order" value="3" placeholder="0"></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>4</td>
                                <td class="question-text">Can you relocate to another city if required?</td>
                                <td class="question-type" data-type="true-false">True or false</td>
                                <td class="question-answer">Yes, No</td>
                                <td class="order-col"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="sequence_order" value="4" placeholder="0"></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>5</td>
                                <td class="question-text">Whats your approach on multi-task management?</td>
                                <td class="question-type" data-type="single-select">Single select</td>
                                <td class="question-answer">I cannot decide, I follow SDLC, Depends on the task</td>
                                <td class="order-col"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="sequence_order" value="5" placeholder="0"></td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          <h5 class="d-flex flex-column sequence-name gap-2" data-seq="1">Add custom sequence</h5><small class="align-items-center">Note: For multi select and range select, direct question selection is allowed. For other types, question can be selected for each answer separately.</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column selection-row gap-2"><label class="form-label">select question for the NEW sequence</label>
                          <div class="select-parent question-parent">
                            <select class="form-select question-dropdown" id="select-ques" data-placeholder="Select question">
                              <option value=""></option>
                              <option value="q1">Are you currently working?</option>
                              <option value="q2">What are your top 5 skills?</option>
                              <option value="q3">What is the largest team size you have handled so far?</option>
                              <option value="q4">Can you relocate to another city if required?</option>
                              <option value="q5">Whats your approach on multi-task management?</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                          <div class="select-parent answer-parent" style="display: none;">
                            <select class="form-select answer-dropdown" id="select-answer" data-placeholder="Select answer">
                              <option value=""></option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'></script>
```